# Column store indexes in SQL Server (datatype conversion errors)

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing, types

After creating column store indexes on dimension tables the fact  query is failing while comparing at join conditions for datatype conversion  errors .Before creating these indexes the queries working fine.

Column store indexes will change any datatype on 8kb datapages at runtime which  was used by SQL Server?

query for reference:

```
(SELECT D.PO_ID,count(*) LOTS

FROM DW_PO_EQP_F F WITH(NOLOCK) 

group by D.PO_ID
) LOTS ON  SUBSTRING(PROP_VALUE,1,4)= LOTS.PO_ID
```

`SUBSTRING(PROP_VALUE,1,4)= LOTS.PO_ID` at this condition query failing at runtime while comparing values when we have column store indexes but with out them the query working fine.we want know the reason whether it will change any datatype or not  and data behaviour at runtime

ERROR:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'IICL' to data type int.

Comment: Table schema definition?

Comment: Joining via a function call is bad design and not at all something I would expect to see in dimension/fact table designs. Also there is no reference to  `'IICL'` anywhere in the query snippet provided, so the error could be somewhere else in the larger query

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: And you define a derived table named "LOTS" that contains a column named "LOTS". That's confusing. But your problem is that the execution plan has changed and now considers rows for the join which cannot be converted implicitly (another bad habit) that were avoided previously. So the source of your problem is not actually in the snippet you posed.